# Laravel Vue Dropzone.js request file return NULL

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, null, dropzone.js

I have a problem, and I can't fix it. I read a lots of forum and issues, but it don't resolve.

The problem is that

`$photos = $request->file('file');
return var_dump($photos);`

bring NULL. I tried to find the error, but I can't

I want store images on server and in a table, then it connecting to an another products table, 
First write in the inputs some data ex. Name,Category, after an other tab upload the images with Dropzone, and save it in one time together.

I am use rowanwins dropzone.

My **... .blade.php**

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ route('product.createnew') }}">

// Other Products inputs ..

//Uploads
<vue-dropzone 
    ref="myVueDropzone" 
    id="dropzone"
    :options="dropzoneOptions">
</vue-dropzone>
// / form and scripts section


 <script>
var url = "{{ route('product.createnew') }}";
console.log(url);
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function () {
        return {
            dropzoneOptions: {
                url: url,
                thumbnailWidth: 150,
                maxFilesize: 2,
                maxFiles: 2,
                acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
                autoDiscover : true,
                clickable : true,
                uploadMultiple :true,
                addRemoveLinks:true,
                headers: {
                    "X-CSRF-TOKEN": document.head.querySelector("[name=csrf-token]").content
                },

            },
            radioButton: '0',
        }
  },
    methods: {
        deleteDropFile(index) {
            this.dropFiles.splice(index, 1)
        }, 
    }
});
```

**My Create Controller**

```
public function create(Request $request)
{   
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
      //Other products input
        'file' => 'nullable|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif|max:2048',

    ]);

    //$products = new Products 
    //$products->save();

   $photos = $request->file('file');
    return var_dump($photos);

    if (!is_array($photos)) {
        $photos = [$photos];
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($photos); $i++) {
        $photo = $photos[$i];
        $savename = sha1(time() . '.' . $request->get('name'))."_$i";

        $images = new ProductImages ([
            'name' => $request->get('name'),
            'post_id'=> $products->id,
            'path'=> public_path('uploads') . '/' . $savename,
            'main'=> 0,
        ]);
        $images->save();

        Image::make($photo)
            ->resize(250, null, function ($constraints) {
                $constraints->aspectRatio();
            })
            ->save(public_path('uploads'). '/' . $savename);
        $photo->move(public_path('uploads'),  $savename);
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

**My routes**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'product'], function () {
    Route::get('/create', 'ProductController@index')->name('product.create'); //View
    Route::post('/createnew', 'ProductController@create')->name('product.createnew');   //Post
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I found what is wrong.
It is the validation

```
        'file' => 'nullable|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif|max:2048',
```

throw the error.

**Thanks**